# Basics regarding $k$-space axis and Energy graph in direct semiconductor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, semiconductor-physics, crystals, dispersion

[image]

We can see from the graphic axes, that energy increases along the y-axis, and k space increases along the y-axis. Considering a direct or indirect semiconductor whichever it doesn't matter, but why does the k-space increases in the x-axis, even though the energy decreases in the conduction band until it reaches the global minima as shown in the picture.
After it reaches the global maxima, E continues to increase while the k space still increases.
I don't understand how the value of k can increase, in spite of the decreasing or increasing value in energy.

P.S: apologies for the messy picture!
from the infinite potential well, we have the E-k relation as E proportional to k^2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to know why k-space values are increasing while the energy of the conduction band first decreases until it reaches the global minima, and after reaching the global minima with respect to a particular k space value, the energy now contrastingly increases, as the k space value also increases.

Comment: Because the energy bands are functions of crystal momentum. This is fundamental to understanding solid state physics.